# How to exact text from one div?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
I have a paragraph like this:

```
row.exact()

    u'<tr bgcolor="#f5f9fc">\n\t\t\t<td valign="top" style="text-align:left;"><a href="/search/sites/ABB1836.asp">ABB</a></td>\n\t\t\t<td nowrap valign="top">+1 713 243 7160</td>\n\t\t\t<td valign="top" style="text-align:left;"><a href="http://www.abb.com" target="_blank">www.abb.com</a></td>\t\t\n\t\t</tr>'
```

I need to get the company name, telephone, and web. I'm trying this code:

```
row.xpath(".//td[1]").extract()
```

Yes it's ok, we can get this below:

```
[u'<td valign="top" style="text-align:left;"><a href="/search/sites/ABB1836.asp">ABB</a></td>']
```

It's still not the text I want, but when I try adding the code text(), I get nothing.

```
row.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").extract()
```

It only returns empty:

```
[]
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I see no divs, no paragraphs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the three fields company name, telephone, and web i.e. the *texts* **ABB**, **+1 713 243 7160** and **www.abb.com** are within three different child `<a>` nodes of three different parent `<td>` nodes. To extract the texts you can use the following solutions:

- `ABB`:

  ```
  row.xpath(".//td[1]/a/text()").extract()
  ```
- `+1 713 243 7160`:

  ```
  row.xpath(".//td[2]/a/text()").extract()
  ```
- `www.abb.com`:

  ```
  row.xpath(".//td[3]/a/text()").extract()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//tr/td[1]/a/text() // for Company Name
//tr/td[2]/text() // Telephone
//tr/td[3]/a/text() // Website
```